# When listening to the sentence, how can you tell that they are talking about more than one elephant?

Tags: liaisons

I am currently learning French on Duolingo, and during one of the exercises, I came across the following sentence:

**Je parle de leurs éléphants.** (Taken from Duolingo)

The problem is that the recording does not have proper liaisons, and without the liaisons, I could not tell whether they were talking about a single elephant or multiple elephants. I would like to know that are there any other clues in this statement that reveal to a listener that the speaker had multiple elephants in mind. I would greatly appreciate your response.

Comment: Sans les liaisons, tu ne peux pas savoir.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Are there any other clues the speaker had multiple elephants in mind?

Certainly not. Proper liaison is the only clue.

The oral version of a sentence without liaison (*Je parle de leurs téléphones*) is 100% ambiguous.

Four strategies to resolve the ambiguity in cases like this:

- **Context.** From what you know, do they jointly own an elephant or do they have a herd?
- **Agreement.** Listen for an adjective that differs in the plural (*éléphant royal* / *éléphants royaux*) or a verb that does the same (*éléphant qui boit* / *éléphants qui boivent*).
- **Ask.** « Parles-tu d'*un seul* éléphant ou de *plusieurs* ? »
- **Echo.** When you talk about the same subject, choose an unambiguous wording (*Donc, pour les éléphants ...*) so they can straighten it out if you're wrong.

Though I love Duolingo, none of these options is possible with their isolated sentence system.

**Edit:** I should add that as far as I know, this liaison is [not optional](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Liaison_obligatoire), as a determiner + noun. Perhaps Duolingo's text-to-speech system is at fault. Or maybe that rule is not always followed in practice.

Comment: If I do not get a better response within a day or two, I would accept your answer as the correct answer.